# Force CREATE PROC when table in the SQL does not exist yet (VB.NET)

Tags: sql, vb.net, ado.net, ado, dao

I am converting a lot of projects from VB6 to VB.NET. Many of these projects use the DAO method CreateQueryDef, something ADO.NET does not. I know there is a way to replicate this method in ADOX using Catalogs, but I wanted to stay with pure ADO.NET. I have been using CREATE PROC to do this, but some of the query def's in the VB6 version mention tables/queries that are not created until later. For example,

```
CreateQueryDef(a, "SELECT ... FROM b")
...
CreateQueryDef(b, "SELECT ...")
```

The way the projects are, it is not possible to simply flip these two lines. I was wondering if there is a way to force `CREATE PROC a AS SELECT ... FROM b` even though b does not exist yet, or if there is a different option in ADO.NET to replicate the CreateQueryDef functionality.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

MS SQL Server allows you to define procedures that use tables that have not yet been created.  As long as they are present when the procedure is executed, it works.

Comment: This is true, but will the warning message generated be interpreted by the ADO routines as an error or failure?

Comment: No error message -- I got confused with the one generated when a procedure references an as-yet undefined stored procedure, something that has caused me grief in the past. Missing tables will not cause this problem.